# How to correctly integrate mailchimp with your website?

Tags: jquery, django, cookies, mailchimp

I wanted to use Mailchimp for my a website which would basically take user's email when submitting,so I got the url from mailchimp which stands like the url below, I added the `post-json` and also `&c=?` at the end!

```
https://xxxxxx.us3.list-manage.com/subscribe/post-json?u=b5d4f5b14088dceec18dc9ca8&amp;id=9d2643cd8e&c=?
```

And integrated it with my jquery like this!

```
$(".mailchimp-submit").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    var this_ = $(this)
    var successMsg = "success_message"
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url:  "url",
        data: this_.serialize(),
        cache       : false,
        dataType    : 'jsonp',
        error       : function(err) {errorMsg()},
        success:(data)=>{
            if (data.result != "success") {
                errorMsg(successMsg)

            } 
            else {
                msg.text()
                msg.css("color","#6610f2")
            }
        },
    })
})
```

And built my form like this!

```
 <form class="mailchimp-submit wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.6s" method="GET" >
      <div class="input-group subcribes">
          <input type="text" name="EMAIL" class="form-control memail" placeholder="abc@example.com" required>
          <button class="btn btn_submit f_size_15 f_500" type="submit">{% trans 'Get Started' %}</button>
      </div>                              
 </form>
```

But I submit my email on FireFox it gives me a warning in console:

```
The resource at “https://xxxxxxx.us3.list-manage.com/subscribe/post-json?u=b…1590645826995&EMAIL=yoneyos382%40whowlft.com&_=1590645826996” was blocked because content blocking is enabled.
```

I thought it's the case with the browser so I tried it on chrome, but on that it gives me an error like this!

```
A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at https://list-manage.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.
```

But when I just submit the form a lot of times at once by clicking on it a lot of times at once,it suddenly gives me an error message "This mail is already submitted" and then I check that mail was being sent to mailchimp!

Strange problem right??
Is it the error from my side or from MailChimp's side??? And how can I fix it?